# SQL query builder for multiple database servers

Tags: c#, sql, rdbms, petapoco

I want to support multiple DBMS', for example: Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc. in my Petapoco ORM project. So I need to use a SQL query builder which supports multiple databases.

A basic example for a query problem:

The query in SQL Server to get the top 2 records is:

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM table_name
```

But in Oracle it's:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ROWNUM <=2
```

Comment: This is a very strange ORM, which doesn't generate SQL queries itself. Why don't you use Entity Framework?

Comment: I prefer petapoco because, Entity Framework is slower than petapoco and bulky.

Comment: The reason PetaPOCO is so quick and light is BECAUSE it doesn't generate the most of the queries itself.  You seem to be defeating the purpose of using it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in `Page` method or `SkipTake`.

It will wrap the paging code around your sql.

eg.

```
db.Fetch<User>(1, 10, "select * from table_name order by id");
```

This will generate something like:

```
select * from (select *, row_number() over (order by id) from table_name) poco
where row_num between 0 and 10
```

This will work for both Oracle and Sql Server. Mysql and Postgres will use their own variants. eg `LIMIT`

Answer (score 0):

Try [DBExtensions](https://github.com/maxtoroq/DbExtensions/wiki)

> [DbExtensions Class Library](http://dbextensions.sf.net/library/)
>
> [SqlBuilder Tutorial](https://github.com/maxtoroq/DbExtensions/wiki/SqlBuilder-Tutorial)

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try [EasyQuery](http://devtools.korzh.com/easyquery/).

This library has Query object which is used to store the query in some internal format and generate SQL. Query object has Formats property which allows you to tune the syntax of generated SQL statements. There are several pre-defined values for most popular DBs (MS SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it's done with [DbExtensions](http://maxtoroq.github.io/DbExtensions/):

```
var db = new Database("name=Northwind");

var query = db.From("products")
   .Take(2);
```